# Using AJAX, Javascript and PHP with MySQL to display search results

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, innerhtml

My aim is to use AJAX to display php search results without having to reload the page.
So far I have been able to get the results, (I'm new to ajax, and I do not know jQuery), currently my only problem is that the search results which I am displaying in a html table appear at the top the page above everything, not in the specified div. I have used the `innerHTML` to try and display it correctly.

Here is my main code:

```
<head>
    <script>
    function searchResults(title) {
        if (title == "") {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML="";
        }
        var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange=function() {

            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                var displayDiv= document.getElementById("response");
                displayDiv.innerHTML=request.responseText;
            }
        }

            request.open("GET", "functions.php?titleA="+title, true);
            request.send();
            document.getElementsById("response").innerHTML="Content";
    }
    </script>
    <title>Anime Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">

        <div class= "header">
        <h1>Search your Database</h1>
    </div> <!-- close header -->

    <div class= "searchA">
        <p>Search your Anime database below</p>
        <form onSubmit="searchResults(titleA)">
            <label>Title</label><input type="text" name="titleA" placeholder="enter title"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>         
        <div id="response">

    </div> <!-- close response -->
</div> <!-- close searchA -->
</body>
```

and here is the php:

```
if (isset($_GET["titleA"])) {
    $title= $_GET["titleA"];
    $connection= connect(); 
    $username= $_SESSION["username"];
    $tableA= $username . "_Anime";
    $queryA= "SELECT * FROM Anime." . "`$tableA` WHERE Title LIKE '%$title%'";
    $resultA= mysqli_query($connection, $queryA);

    if ($resultA == false) {
        die("no results found");
    }

    $numRows= mysqli_num_rows($resultA);

    echo "<table class= 'tSearch'>
            <thead>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Alt Title</th>
                <th>Seasons</th>
                <th>Episodes</th>
                <th>OVA's</th>
                <th>Movies</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Downloaded</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";

    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($resultA, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Title"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Alt_Title"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Seasons"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Total_Episodes"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["OVAS"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Movies"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Status"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Downloaded"] . "</td>";

                echo "</tr>"; 
            }

                echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";

            mysqli_close($connection);

                if ($resultA == false) {
                    echo mysqli_error($connection);
                }
            }
```

I have of course spend many hours trying to find out whats wrong, I do plan on learning jQuery, but for now I just really want to get this to work, so please do not tell me to use jQuery,

EDIT: link to a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

My browser is Safari 7.0.4, I tried Firefox and got the same problem.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can we see the error messages your getting if you're getting any?

Comment: "my only problem is that the search results which I am displaying in a html table appear at the top the page above everything," ??

Comment: Im not getting any error messages, here is a link to a picture, i couldn't upload because my rep isn't high enough.http://i.imgur.com/EJKhaTi.png

Comment: Your JavaScript code seems right on first sight. But I detected an sql injection vulnerability in your php code. Please use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysql_real_escpace_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Thank you Sascha, I know about the mysql_real_escape string, but its hosted locally and will never be put on a public server, i will add it in for completeness's sake later though. Im purely creating this website in order to learn more about web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, rewriting your code from the start really does help. The problem was that in my javascript I was sending the title as just +title, i really should have changed this to title.value, this is why the php wasn't understanding what i was trying to send it. Thanks Daniel for all the help.
I will display all my code below.
javascript:

```
    function searchData() {
        var title= document.getElementById("titleA");
        var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange= function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=request.responseText;                 
            } 
        }


        request.open("POST", "functions.php", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        request.send("title="+title.value);
    }

    </script>
```

The php:

```
if (isset($_POST["title"])) {
$title= $_POST["title"];
```

} 
    $connection= connect();

```
    $username= $_SESSION["username"];

    $tableA= $username . "_Anime";

    $queryA= "SELECT * FROM Anime." . "`$tableA` WHERE Title LIKE '%$title%'";

    $resultA= mysqli_query($connection, $queryA);

    if ($resultA == false) {
        die("no results found");
    }


    $numRows= mysqli_num_rows($resultA);

    echo "<table class= 'tSearch'>
            <thead>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Alt Title</th>
                <th>Seasons</th>
                <th>Episodes</th>
                <th>OVA's</th>
                <th>Movies</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Downloaded</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";

    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($resultA, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Title"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Alt_Title"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Seasons"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Total_Episodes"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["OVAS"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Movies"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Status"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["Downloaded"] . "</td>";

                echo "</tr>"; 
            }

                echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";

            mysqli_close($connection);

                if ($resultA == false) {
                    echo mysqli_error($connection);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here, Let me give you a generic layout:

This may be the easiest way to use ajax, I use this in my every project. First link the external ajax.js then you can use the below script.

I don't exactly know where you have done wrong base on your description, but this works for me even locally. One reason may be your `#response` isn't loaded yet when you execute the script.

### ajax.js

```
function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
    var x;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        { //New Browsers
            x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
        { //IE5, IE6
        x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    x.open( meth, url, true );
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
       return true; 
    }
}
```

### Script Tag Request for Ajax:

```
var ajax = ajaxObj("GET", "functions.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
ajax.send("titleA="+title);
```

### Or if you prefer JQuery:

```
//You need to load jQuery first before using this
$(function() {  //This line means when document is ready
    var ajax = ajaxObj("GET", "functions.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                $("#response").html(ajax.responseText);
            }
        }
    ajax.send("titleA="+title);
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, i didn't think to put it into an external script. I do actually believe that the script loads before the, because if i get rid of the  if (isset($_GET["titleA"])) { $title= $_GET["titleA"]; then the website loads everything in the database straight away. I don't understand why it does that, as i have put it in a function which should only activate when you submit the form.

Comment: the script loads before the div*

Comment: no, the problem you have i think is maybe outside the external ajax script, it is the document cannot seems to find the right div to put the response.

Comment: I tried putting all the javascript in the external file, however as soon as the page loads, the database is searched and all the results are still being displayed.

Comment: that is because you will trigger the script on page load, that's normal.

Comment: The problem was that i had an include functions.php that i forgot to remove, but daniel,shouldn't the javascript functions only execute when called?

Comment: if you are talking about the jquery one, it functions when page ready, if not the case, there must be some other js script outside the function scope to be ran when page load. **Or** you included a PHP file that echos when page loaded and not from ajax trigger.

Comment: yes,i found out it was the latter, my php was being echoed because i had included, now that that problem is over, nothing displays when i run the search.

Comment: if you don't see anything and there is no error on the js part, the php has errors, please use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top and check if it echoed anything.

Comment: also, i suggest you using `post` instead of `get`

Comment: i found out that the ajaxReturn() function returns false, not true, i did this by writing an if statement, so that if its not true it will alert("false"); I don't think there anything wrong with the php as all i did was remove the include statement, i didn't the touch php code

Comment: it returned false id because there is not response **yet**. meaning the PHP is not returning a response, thus meaning it halted on an error

Comment: my php simply consists of echoes, how would i return a response then? you have seen my php code in my original question

Comment: I suggest put echoes all around in the PHP code for debugging, to see if values are passed correctly. e.g. `echo $title` to start with, once you are sure the ajax is ok, move on to the function

Comment: i tried that, but i saw no output, its as if the php code isn't executing.

Comment: can you try `$_GET["titleA"]`?

Comment: i have, here are screenshots of the relevant code. http://imgur.com/ZWCl7Aj,izgi3M0,iv5SIZG

Comment: are you using post in php as well?

Comment: try `alert("hello world")` under `true` in your image. also, you cannot use an else

Comment: i don't get an alert.

Comment: Oh~ I know why, you see in your image `...ajaxObj("POST"...` and you just said `$_GET`, please correct the PHP to `if(isset($_POST["titleA"])) {$title= $_POST["titleA"];` until unified

Comment: i changed it, it didn't help

Comment: can you try in your PHP comment out the code and try `if(isset($_POST["titleA"])) {echo "test"}`

Comment: its not working, when i enter my search query in the search box, i don't think it connects to the php, i did what you said, and i also put a echo "hello world" statement in my php, none it echo'd

Comment: try if(isset($_POST["titleA"])) {echo "test"; exit()}

Comment: try in your js use this: `request.send("titleA="+title);`

Comment: aghh still nothing. maybe i should just learn jquery and try this again.

Comment: have you check your `request.send(...)`? there shouldn't be a `?` in there

Comment: yeah i changed that before

Comment: sorry, don't know where went wrong... can't help you further. so sorry